# Android UIAutomatorViewer is locating my mobile menu icons even though Opened app screenshot is taken

Tags: appium, appium-android

unable to locate the mobile app locators with uiautomatorviewer

Hi, i'm new to appium. i'm learning the appium basics and i'm facing a issue with uiautomatorviewer. i opened a android app in my mobile and i took screen shot of that app page. and when i tried to find the element locators with that it is showing the locators of mobile menu like "amazon,Skype,flipkart" etc menu. how to overcome this?
in the attached screen shot you can find the details

[image: UI Automator Issue screenshot]

Comment: I guess the menu is hidden.

Comment: but it is not even able to find the elements in the app.. it is finding my mobile menu